# c++: отслеживание процесса считывания из файла при использовании stl библиотек

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, асинхронность, fstream

Считываю большой объём данных из файла (1ГБ+) с помощью stl библиотеки `fstream`:

```
file.read(fileBuffer, fileBufferSize);
```

Подскажите, есть ли какая-то возможность отслеживать динамику считывания из файла (сколько уже данных считано)?

Есть в отдельном потоке индикация обработки считанных данных, хотелось бы добавить и индикацию считывания данных, чтобы было видно, что работа программы не зависла.

Comment: Считывайте в цикле небольшими блоками и обновляйте прогресс после каждого.

Comment: @user7860670, но производительности это не очень хорошее решение все таки

Comment: Вы думаете, что считывать блоками килобайт по 64 существенно медленнее, чем один блок в гигабайт? сомнительно...

Comment: @Harry, если жесткий диск в этот момент мучают несколько приложений, то возможно - т.е. будет тратиться время дополнительное на поиск и тд., но хотя вы может и правы - можно проверить

Comment: По 64 кб медленнее раза в 2. Надо по 1-8 МБ блоки делать.